# javascript .get function works in development but not production

Tags: javascript, express

Below is code where the client is trying to get data from the server. Locally running my server on node.js, this works great. However, when I push to my server, I get `/getSettings 500 (Internal Server Error)`. My index gets hit when the other request is made `'/'` so I know the endpoint can be hit. But why not this other get?

Node.js is running on my server as a runtime.

SERVER code (app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var Config = require('./config.js'), conf = new Config();
const app= express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, function(error){
if(error) {
    console.log('Server failed to listen: ', error)
} else{
    console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port)
}
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get("/getSettings", function(require, response){
  response.json({ configuration: conf });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

CLIENT Code:

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {   
        $.get("/getSettings", function( data ) 
        {
            //do stuffs
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, your `server` variable is confusingly named.  That is not the server - that is the `app` object.  `app.listen()` returns the actual server object.

Comment: Is the web page that the client code is in loaded from the same Express server?  And, where does the `/subfolder/sub2/public` come from in the URL `/subfolder/sub2/public/getSettings`?  That's not anywhere in your code.  Is there some sort of hosting infrastructure that is adding that?

Comment: Thanks! I will rename it to app so it’s more accurately named. 

And good eyes, I keep forgetting I’m operating in a sunflower. I’ll try changing the path to see if to include the entire relative path for getSettings as well.

Comment: I tried changing the path and that didn't work. I updated my original post to include a picture of the setup I have in cpanel.

Comment: Well, it seems pretty clear that the `/subfolder/sub2` is coming from your cpanel setup, but I don't know anything about that hosting configuration to know what to suggest or what you're trying to accomplish by setting it that way.

Comment: I removed the two subfolders and put it in the root, and I still have the same issue.

My app.get to retrieve index file now is:
`app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});`

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` Still get this even when I have a very simple get definition in server, and client get code.

Comment: I think this request goes to your Apache server and not to your Node app. Are you sure you are proxying all requests to Node server from Apache?

Comment: 500 is a very generic error message, it basically just means "something went wrong" on the server. Does your hosting provider not allow you to view any server logs that might provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. `/getSettings` needs an empty folder called getSettings. So if anyone else has a scenario where root works fine, but no other routes do, this may likely be your issue.